# jprofiler offline profiling on remote server jvm throws out of memory

Tags: jboss, jvm, jprofiler

I am using jdk1.5 and jboss4.0.4 on windows 64bit and have multiple application(war) files in a EAR file. 
I have started the JVM on a remote server with the jprofiler agent parameter and offline parameter in run.bat file, also copied the config file from the local to make use of the ID parameter as well.

The JBOSS fails to come up with error out of jvm memory, however same successfully runs if I do online profiling. I have added only one trigger with max of 2 intervals (every 1 hour) to capture CPU and stop capturing with a sleep of 2secs.

Can some one help me how to fix this issue,without increasing the JVM?

Comment: Is this an OutOfMemoryError while JBoss is running or does the JVM print a message at startup saying that it cannot allocate enough memory for the heap?

Comment: I get the following error, while Jboss is coming up and do not get start the services further.                                         07:25:39,730 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space Note: Same works,without any issues when I run with remote online mode.

Comment: what is your -Xmx value?